# How to do tuple comparison?

Tags: sql, sqlite, row-value-expression

Trying the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506729/sql-tuple-comparison) but in SQLite. In my application I need to do this type of query:

```
SELECT First, Last, Score
FROM mytable
WHERE
    ('John',  'Jordan',  5) <= (First, Last, Score )
    AND (First, Last, Score) <= ('Mike',  'Taylor',  50) 
ORDER BY First, Last, Score
LIMIT 1
```

And get the answer `('Liz', 'Jordan', 2)`, given this data:

| First | Last | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Liz | Jordan | 2 |
| John | Jordan | 2 |
| Liz | Lemon | 10 |
| Mike | Taylor | 100 |
| John | Jackson | 1000 |
| Mike | Wayne | 1 |
| Liz | Lemon | 20 |
| Liz | Meyers | 5 |
| Bruce | Jackson | 1 |

How to accomplish this in SQLite? This is a toy example, my application more columns and data types and hundreds of million of rows. If the solution is easily extensible to more/less columns, that's even better.

> Tuples are ordered lexicographically, meaning that the sequences are ordered the same as their first differing elements. For example, (1,2,x) < (1,2,y) returns the same as x < y.
>  It's worth noting that SQL-92 (and mysql, oracle, postresql) implements this correctly. The standard uses "row value constructor" to denote what I'm calling a tuple. The behavior is defined in excruciating detail in [part 8.2.7, page 209](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

SQL to create the example:

```
create table mytable ( First char(20), Last char(20), Score int );
insert into mytable values ('Liz', 'Jordan', 2);
insert into mytable values ('John', 'Jordan', 2);
insert into mytable values ('Liz', 'Lemon', 10);
insert into mytable values ('Mike', 'Taylor', 100);
insert into mytable values ('John', 'Jackson', 1000);
insert into mytable values ('Mike', 'Wayne', 1);
insert into mytable values ('Liz', 'Lemon', 20);
insert into mytable values ('Liz', 'Meyers', 5);
insert into mytable values ('Bruce', 'Jackson', 1);
create unique index 'UNIQ' on mytable (First, Last, Score);
```

Comment: sqlite now has tuples, but be aware that if any value is `null` then it may behave differently than expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support tuple comparisons. But a row constructor is a kind of shorthand. You can get the same result with a more complicated WHERE clause. I've omitted the `LIMIT 1` clause to make it easier to see that both queries return the same set. (On platforms that support row constructors, that is.)

This comparison

```
ROW(a,b) <= ROW(c,d)
```

is equivalent to

```
a < c OR (a = c AND b <= d)
```

And you can extend that to as many columns as you need.

```
SELECT First, Last, Score
FROM mytable
WHERE
      (('John' < First) OR 
       ('John' = First AND 'Jordan' < Last) OR 
       ('John' = First AND 'Jordan' = Last AND 5 <= Score))
  AND ((First < 'Mike') OR 
       (First = 'Mike' AND Last < 'Taylor') OR 
       (First = 'Mike' AND Last = 'Taylor' AND Score <= 50))
ORDER BY First, Last, Score

Liz  Jordan  2
Liz  Lemon  10
Liz  Lemon  20
Liz  Meyers  5
```

I did not test this with NULLs in the data.

---

As of 2018, SQLite *does* support tuple comparison. The OP's query produces the expected output using the SQL statements provided. This way of writing the query also works. (I find `between ... and ...` more readable.)

```
SELECT First, Last, Score
FROM mytable
WHERE (First, Last, Score ) between ('John',  'Jordan',  5) and ('Mike',  'Taylor',  50) 
ORDER BY First, Last, Score
Limit 1
```

I don't know how long ago this was introduced.

Comment: I wonder if the mysql optimizer is smart enough to know this is the same as the tuple syntax.

Comment: Outdated?  according to this site, SQLite supports tuple comparisons: http://www.sql-workbench.net/dbms_comparison.html

Comment: [row values](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) support added on 2016-10-14 for release 3.15.0, with several fixes later on, last one on 2018-04-02 (3.23.0). See https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

I've been circumventing the lack of tuple comparison by using string concatenation (`||`) and a character sequence to ensure the fields don't "merge" and cause incorrect matches (`-`).

```
(First, Last, Score) <= ('Mike',  'Taylor',  50)
```

becomes

```
First||' - '||Last||' - '||Score <= 'Mike'||' - '||'Taylor'||' - '||'50'
```

or

```
First||' - '||Last||' - '||Score <= 'Mike - Taylor - 50'
```

so your `SELECT` would be

```
SELECT First, Last, Score
FROM mytable
WHERE
    'John - Jordan - 5' <= First||' - '||Last||' - '||Score
    AND First||' - '||Last||' - '||Score <= 'Mike - Taylor - 50'
ORDER BY First, Last, Score
LIMIT 1
```

String concatenation is pretty costly and less terse but it works the same way and looks very similar.

Comment: This is general-purpose only if you escape the concatenated strings. Do you think this has better performance than @catcall's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite's `Raw value` added in `3.15.0`: https://sqlite.org/rowvalue.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).