# Use own tuples in JOIN statement

Tags: sql, join, tuples, relation

is it possible use own tuples as a source for an JOIN statement?

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

`SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users u
INNER JOIN {{tupl1},{tupel2},{tupel3},...}`

Comment: Could you describe your problem more thoroughly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 you use the [Table Value Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx).

```
declare @T table(ID int)
insert into @T values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

select *
from @T as T1 
  inner join (
              values (1, 'Row 1'), 
                     (2, 'Row 2')
             ) as T2(ID, Col1)
    on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: Known as a 'table value constructor', it originates from the SQL-92 Standard.

Comment: @onedaywhen - Thanks, and now when I know what it is called I found the documentation as well :).

Comment: You can also add that it's more often used in `INSERT INTO table VALUES ...`

Answer (score 2):

Many dbms platforms support common table expressions.

```
with my_own_tuples as (
    select 'value1' as column1, 'value2' as column2
    union all 
    select 'value3', 'value4'
    union all 
    select 'value5', 'value6'
)
select column1, column2
from my_other_table
inner join my_own_tuples on (my_own_tuples.column1 = my_other_table.column1);
```

[PostgreSQL Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

MySql has some [support for Tuples with comparisons and equality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5507933/314291), although I'm struggling to find a definitive reference for this.

For example:

```
SELECT *
    FROM table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON (t1.Col1, t1.Col2) = (t2.Col1, t2.Col2);
```

And

```
SELECT *
    FROM table1 t1
       WHERE (t1.Col1, t1.Col2) <= ('SomeValue', 1234);
```

[SqlFiddle showing these here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d95c/2)